# finding the non common element between two arrays

Tags: java, collections, set

In an interview it was asked to find non- common elements between two string arrays.

```
Eg: String a[]={"a","b","c","d"}; 
String b[]={"b","c"}; 
O/p should be a,d
```

I have answered to the question that in Java Set is implemented using HashTable. The code with Set is much simpler:

```
String[] a = {"a","b","c","d"};
String[] b = {"b", "c"};

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(a.length);
for(String s : a){
    set.add(s);
}
for(String s : b){
    set.remove(s);
}
return set;
```

now my query is that is there any other better approach to achieve this

Comment: Using this approach you would miss the strings only present in `b`, right?

Comment: It looks like the input is sorted... is this by chance, or is it guaranteed?

Comment: @aioobe its by chance please advise the approach if string is not sorted one then../

Comment: @aioobe well yeah its by chance , please advise what to do if string is not sorted one

Comment: @aioobe yes very much only contain elements in a but please advise if the array are not sorted one then what should i do in that case

Comment: What should the result be for `[x, y]`, `[x,z]`?

Comment: I can't help thinking that this question would be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com than here.

Answer (score 6):

If `[x,y], [x,z]` should yield `[y,z]` here's what I suggest:

```
String[] a = {"a","b","c","d"};
String[] b = {"b", "c", "x"};

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
for (String s : new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(b)) {
    if (!set.add(s))    // if it's already present
        set.remove(s);  // remove it from the result
}
```

If on the other hand, `[x,y], [x,z]` should yield `[y]`, I would suggest

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
set.removeAll(Arrays.asList(b));
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the `remove` is redundant right? Set's don't allow duplicates.

Comment: Nope. It ensures that duplicates are removed.

Comment: @aioobe The add method in set does not add an element to the set if already present. Can you elaborate the need of remove? Read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)

Comment: If an element did not get added to the Set, why remove it?

Comment: @ChetanKinger, I interpret the question as to find all elements that are not present in both arrays. In this case, if `add` returns false, it means that the element was already present (i.e. it came from `a`) in which case it was present in both arrays and it should be removed. Is my explanation clear?

Comment: @aioobe Your explanation is solid but the OP wants something else : `yes very much only contain elements in a`

Comment: "finding the non common element between two arrays" seems to suggest that he's after elements that are present in one of the two arrays. (This also seems to be Jon Skeets interpretation).

Comment: @aioobe You are right. Your answer matches the question title but the OP clarified in the comments what he wanted.

Comment: @aioobe The OP confirmed this in the comment `yes very much only contain elements in a`. Surprisingly, this was actually in response to your comment which has now been deleted.

Comment: @aioobe Downvote retracted! This answer should be the one to be accepted.

Answer (score 6):

You can shorten the code by

```
TreeSet set = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(a));
set.removeAll(Arrays.asList(b));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/j7zGYW)

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala how a set can have duplicate?

Comment: @KickButtowski, I said it will not work, if list has duplicates.

Comment: How are duplicates relevant, @SaurabhJhunjhunwala?  The task is to find non-common elements.  This approach will work very well.

Comment: Depends on if you see two `.equal` elements as two distinct elements. But that view is kind of silly.

Answer (score 5):

In effect, this expands upon Jon Skeet's answer, but does so using Java 8's streams.

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(a)
                        .filter((s) -> Arrays.stream(b).noneMatch(s::equals))
                        .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

The main tenants of the code are:

- Filter out any element contained in A if and only if it does not exist in B (through the short-circuiting terminal operator `noneMatch`), checking if the element is equal to anything in that stream.
- Collect the results to a `String[]`.

Another approach using `Set`, and again using streams:

```
Set<String> setA = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(b));

String[] setResult = setA.stream()
                         .filter((s) -> !setB.contains(s))
                         .toArray(String[]::new);
```

The main issue with the non-Set code as pointed out was that it is quadratic time in the worst case.  This code here takes advantage of the constant access time to `Set#contains`, and should run in about linear time.

Comment: Note that since you iterate over `b` for each element of `a` this yields a quadratic complexity. In fact I wouldn't advice on using streams in this use case. This algorithm would be more readable in the form of nested for-loops in my opinion.

Comment: This is true and lamentable.  Let me come up with an approach that makes use of sets.

Comment: You don't need to go through `toList`. You can use `toArray` directly on the stream.

Comment: You can't get a `String[]` from `toArray`, though.  You can only get an `Object[]`.  Attempts to downcast will result in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: You would use the other `toArray` method: `.toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: Good tip.  I'll add that in.

Answer (score 3):

I would handle this in three steps:

- Find all elements in `a` but not `b`
- Find all elements in `b` but not `a`
- Add those two sets together

So for example:

```
Set<String> aSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
Set<String> bSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(b));

Set<String> aNotB = new HashSet<>(aSet);
aNotB.removeAll(bSet);

Set<String> bNotA = new HashSet<>(bSet);
bNotA.removeAll(aSet);

Set<String> onlyOne = new HashSet<>(aNotB);
onlyOne.addAll(bNotA);
```

(The stream code in Java 8 may well make this simpler too...)

The code could be made shorter if you don't mind modifying `aSet` and `bSet`, but I find this version easier to read.

Comment: `yes very much only contain elements in a`. I guess the OP is only interested in one side of the equation?

Comment: @ChetanKinger: That's commenting on what the OP's current code does. I would contend that it doesn't answer the question as written.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String a[]={"a","b","c","d"}; 
String b[]={"b","c"}; 

List aLst = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
List bLst = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(b));

aLst.removeAll(bLst);
System.out.println(aLst);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are only English letters (or over a small alphabet.. even ASCII) I would rather use a boolean[] by char value instead of HashSets etc to somewhat improve performance.